# docker: command not found; on running docker commands on remote server using shell script

Tags: bash, docker, shell

I am trying to run **docker** commands from a shell script in a remote server using ssh. I am able to execute the command manually on the remote server but when I run it through the script, it shows this error:

```
+ eloquent_shamir
+ echo eloquent_shamir
+ docker version
/tmp/nmon_jstat_scripts_to_container.sh: line 4: docker: command not found
copying nmon.sh in container:eloquent_shamir
+ echo 'copying nmon.sh in container:eloquent_shamir'
+ docker cp /tmp/nmon.sh eloquent_shamir:/opt/
/tmp/nmon_jstat_scripts_to_container.sh: line 6: docker: command not found
copying jstat.sh in container:eloquent_shamir
+ echo 'copying jstat.sh in container:eloquent_shamir'
+ docker cp /tmp/jstat.sh eloquent_shamir:/opt/
/tmp/nmon_jstat_scripts_to_container.sh: line 9: docker: command not found
+ docker exec -it eloquent_shamir /bin/bash -c 'chmod 777 /opt/nmon.sh'
/tmp/nmon_jstat_scripts_to_container.sh: line 12: docker: command not found
+ docker exec -it eloquent_shamir /bin/bash -c 'chmod 777 /opt/jstat.sh'
/tmp/nmon_jstat_scripts_to_container.sh: line 14: docker: command not found
```

Here is my script which I am running in the remote server:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
echo $1
docker version
echo "copying nmon.sh in container:$1"
docker cp /tmp/nmon.sh $1:/opt/
echo "copying jstat.sh in container:$1"
docker cp /tmp/jstat.sh $1:/opt/

docker exec -it $1 /bin/bash -c "chmod 777 /opt/nmon.sh"
docker exec -it $1 /bin/bash -c "chmod 777 /opt/jstat.sh"

echo "...................."

echo "creating NMON_OUTPUT dir in container:$1"
docker exec -it $1 /bin/bash -c "mkdir /opt/NMON_OUTPUT"
echo "creating JSTAT_OUTPUT dir in container:$1"
docker exec -it $1 /bin/bash -c "mkdir /opt/JSTAT_OUTPUT"

echo "...................."
sleep 10
```

Here "eloquent_shamir" is container name.

Comment: Doing these things with `docker exec` seems odd.  Why wouldn't the Dockerfile set up the container filesystem appropriately (including putting a responsible set of permissions on the shell scripts)?

Comment: As dockerfile might not be accessible to us.

Comment: `docker: command not found` seems like a pretty clear error, and not something programming-related.

Comment: when I am using 'ssh u_name@IP' and manually running docker commands, it's working fine. Error occurs only when I am using the above shell script to run the commands.

Comment: You could check the PATH variable (with "echo $PATH") manually and in the script. Maybe something changes PATH before running docker through script.